# Why is my Array getting turned into a string in HTTP POST?

Tags: jquery, http, post

I have a `<select multiple />` tag that get's an array value.

When I append that value to my FormData:

```
var formData = new FormData();
$(icFields).filter(":not(:file)").each( function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var inputType = $(input).attr("type");
        var inputKey = $(input).attr("name");
        if( typeof(inputKey) != "undefined" || inputKey == "" ) {
            var keyArr = inputKey.split("-");
            if(keyArr[0] != "temp") {

                var value = $(input).val();

                var encrypted = $(input).data(ENCRYPTION_KEY);
                if(encrypted) {
                    value = CryptoJS.SHA3( value );
                } 

                formData.append( inputKey, value );
            }

        }
    });
```

What I get in the request body on the server is a string.

For example: `formData.append("genre", ["0","1","2"]);`
In request body I see: `{ genre: '1,2,3' }`

I am using ajax. I'm also setting `contentType: false` and `processData: false` in the ajax call.

Comment: What kind of content does a false contentType hold ? False files ?

Comment: what if you use `formData[inputKey]= value;` instead of `formData.append( inputKey, value );` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the middleware I was using to parse the request body had a bug in it "body-parser".

I changed it to the "multer" library and all is well.